# iis 7.5 ASP.net hanging requests

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, webserver

I am having some performance issues with my iis webserver. It is hanging randomly and I am trying to figure out how to speed up the server. I enabled Failed request tracing on the server and set it to generate a log when the request is over 3 seconds.

The resulting logs(xml) dont show much but there is a point in the compact performance log that indicates what part of the log the server is hanging on. Below is the part of the log where the large time loss is occurring.

`65. i GENERAL_GET_URL_METADATA PhysicalPath="", AccessPerms="513" 17:46:32.577`

`66. i HANDLER_CHANGED OldHandlerName="", NewHandlerName="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0", NewHandlerModules="ManagedPipelineHandler", NewHandlerScriptProcessor="", NewHandlerType="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 17:46:32.577`

`67. i VIRTUAL_MODULE_UNRESOLVED Name="FormsAuthentication", Type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" 17:46:47.771`

I am not sure what Handler changed is but it is taking a long time, any tips would be great on where to start looking.

Comment: Do you have any iFrame elements in your WebForms?

Comment: No not that I know of

Comment: Check when apppool recycles and what time it takes for that.

Answer (score 8):

It is hard to come up with a solution without having any piece of code in sight. Here are some general hints/tips you can follow in order to have great performances with an ASP.NET application.

- The fastest way to do a request is to not do it in the first place. Try caching everything that can be cached. There are server-side caches and client-side caches. Each have their own uses, but you are not limited to only one type.
- Make sure you do not cache and/or keep references of any request-related objects into memory. ASP.NET have a limited number of concurrent requests and keeping a request reference in memory will hang your server if it runs out of threads
- Close the request as soon as you are done with it
- Everything that is not needed by the client at the time of the request should be done in the background
- Make sure you have no memory leak in your application. Garbage Collections are often the cause of hangs in ASP.NET application. When garbage collecting, all running threads are paused. This is especially true for `Gen 2` garbage collections. You can [enable background generation 2 garbage collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#background_server_garbage_collection).
- Isolate the problematic code. Use a profiler and see which type of request is CPU-intensive. Then dig deeper and see what inside that request makes it slow.
- In any well-balanced application, objects should either be short-lived and live forever. In the case of an ASP.NET application, the objects created during the course of a request should ideally die within that request or during the next GC gen 0.
- Consider object pooling for large objects and objects that are long to initialize
- Make sure your app pool doesn't totally crash and restarts (look the IIS logs and/or the Windows Events)

Some useful debugging tools you can use:

- [LeanSentry](https://www.leansentry.com/). Great for diagnosing ASP.NET server hangs
- [windbg](http://www.windbg.org/). High learning curve but by far the most powerful debugging tool you can use
- [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=28567). Useful for analyzing ETW events like I/O or CPU usage

Comment: Sorry it won't let me fully apply the bounty after it's expired and I've been away for a while. At least, I cannot find a way to apply the full bounty.

Comment: No problem Michael :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to improve server performance. But before that you should start with checking CPU usage during the "hang". An infinite loop in the application code may cause this behavior. Unless there is I/O, locking, or sleeps in the loop, you will be able to see it from the CPU usage as you will get exactly one full core's worth of CPU usage for each infinite loop.

[Help link to improve server performance](http://securitywing.com/8-effective-ways-to-improve-iis-7-5-performance/)

More Info:
I can see entry related to VIRTUAL MODULE UNRESOLVED: which is related to bad use of Response.Redirect(url); Also make sure you have deployed your app on integrated mode on IIS.

here's a simple checklist you might want to reconsider:
Always pre-compiling your site, as opposed to copying it! you might gain a significant performance boost compiling your website before deployment: [ASP.NET Precompilation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx)

Do not run the production application with debug="true" enabled, when debug flag is true in your web.config, Much more memory is used within the application at runtime, and since some additional debug paths are enabled, codes can execute much slower
Check your Web.config file to ensure trace is disabled in the  section
IIS 7.5 comes with the [Auto-Start Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260%28v=azure.10%29.aspx). WAS (Windows Process Activation Service) starts all the application pools that are configured to start automatically, ensure that your application pool is configured to AlwaysRunning in the IIS 7.5 applicationHost.config, [check out here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) for more detail.

Every asp.net server can be well configured by aspnet.config file located in the root of the framework folder. Ensure that Publisher Evidence for Code Access Security (CAS) is set to false in your aspnet.config file, This might increase the initial page load when you restart the ASP.NET app pool. you can read [more about it here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfedev/archive/2008/11/26/best-practice-generatepublisherevidence-in-aspnet-config.aspx).

Also you might want to try [Application Initialization Module for IIS 7.5](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization), this module also available on IIS 8.0 can decrease the response time for first requests by pre-loading worker processes

Comment: The cpu doesn't do much on first page load.  The website is fairly simple and should be very fast, there is very little custom application code on top of the asp.net framework.