# Thousands of IIS requests stuck on EndRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've been trying to diagnose an issue pertaining to thousands of hung/stuck **EndRequest** requests in IIS. This is becoming a large problem for us as we're hitting the concurrent connection cap after about a week or two and have to recycle the whole application pool to clear the request list.

Because this is a live application, I have limited troubleshooting options, so anything that would halt or bring down the application pool I am not allowed to do.

**IIS Information**

- Concurrent connection cap is set to its maximum of 65535.
- Configuration debug in the web config is set to false and we have a
  timeout set at 110 seconds.
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Version 6.2 (Build 9200)
- IIS Version 8.5.9600.16384
- The long running requests have 0 data transfer, checked with
  WireShark.

I'm pretty much at a loss on why these aren't timing out. I've set all the appropriate settings - the ones I could find from MSDN and other sources. We have a very, very hard time replicating this on our development environment so it's been blind testing for the most part. I've found articles and such on other state hangs, but I cannnot find anything on why a request in the EndRequest state will not time out.

Advanced Settings Page:
https://postimg.org/image/gxec32kmt/

Application Pool Requests Page:
https://postimg.org/image/qupcw57o5/

Web Config:
https://postimg.org/image/5xt4rh1xh/

**Update 1**

<s>I did a bit of digging into our fallback that is supposed to close connections after an hour of no usage. We seem to currently have 10,153 sessions still active with a last active time of 3 days ago. I've stepped through this function quite a bit and it seems to be working as intended. It goes through the list of sessions and anyone over an hour of inactivity has their `WebSocketHandler.Close()` method called. However it seems some sessions are refusing to close after the method is being called. We have logging in place to tell us if any exceptions are being thrown during the run but it seems as though it's running as expected.</s>
This was my mistake. I was running against an old sessions data pull. A current pull of the session data shows no sessions running greater then their specified time. This means that the `WebSocketHandler.Close()` was called on them and they were removed from our in-memory list.

**Update 2**

NETSTAT using netstat -s on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/qBbZ4gJ1

**Update 3**

Correction to update 1. Can a connection close be called and fail? If so, then we're accidentally orphaning the reference to the connection in our server. I would still expect the IIS timeout to kick in however, there must be some catches to it collecting requests.

Comment: The biggest killer ive seen for IIS issues like that is people opening DBs and not specifically closing them and waiting for GC to do that for them

Comment: Anything in Global.asax in Application_EndRequest()?

Comment: @BugFinder I would expect that to eventually exhaust the database connection pool though

Comment: I think it also depends on what method database connectivity is used

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212838/iis-7-5-asp-net-hanging-requests may be helpful

Comment: @MatthewEvans We don't seem to have Application_EndRequest defined, so nothing there.

Comment: @BugFinder Our database isn't used by any of the requests directly. All requests that modify data is done so in memory. We have a scheduled task that runs and goes through our users list in ram and writes the data back to the DB every 5 seconds if the data has changed.

Comment: What does NETSTAT show?  A little more info might help - are these (ASPX) webpages, webservices, ... ?

Comment: @Henk Holterman
This is a web api service called by our mobile game. No pages are being served. A user connects to our game and we open a web socket connection to them and keep it alive as long as there is activity coming across the pipe. 

Running NETSTAT now.

Comment: @HenkHolterman
Hm so I ran a standard NETSTAT command, and it's taking a long time to run through all the established connections. So I ran a NETSTAT -s. Updated my post with the findings.

Comment: Post the results as text, and not on a wanky external site.

Comment: And we still know very little, for instance does your server call other services?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The only service that's called is to the facebook open graph. This is done once during login for verification auth tokens. The requests being made from app > server are all done internally on memory-mapped data loaded from SQL on initial server startup.

I put a pastebin of the netstat result. https://pastebin.com/embed_js/qBbZ4gJ1

Comment: Did you ever end up resolving this issue?